# MYSQL: Values of a column where two other columns have same value

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table say table1 with three columns lets name them col1 col2 and col3. I have a suspicion that col2 and col3 have some values that are identical i.e. to say there are some rows where col2 = col3. In case, if for these rows col1 is the same I will have no problem in my application. But how to check for those where col1 = col2 but they don't point to the same col1 value.

I mean `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col2 = col3` gives me records for col2 = col3 in same rows. what I want for each col2 value search col3 if it is same send those records

Something like this (this is pseudo SQL) but in MYSQL

`SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM table1
foreach col2 
    same_records = SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = col3
    records UNION same_records
end foreach
SELECT records`

Is there is a way to get these results (if they exist)? I believe that I have to use self-join on the table.

Comment: You mean `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col2 = col3 AND col1 != col2` ?

Comment: @Akina Please check, I have edited my question.

Comment: mmm... incomprehensible... maybe try to show an example of the source data and the result for it?

Comment: @Akina Please check, I have edited my question again.

Comment: Сorrect me if I'm wrong. You want 1) Eject all records with `col3` field values which not exists in any record in `col2` field. 2) Select `DISTINCT col1` for the remaining records.

Comment: @Akina col3 values which does exist in col2

Comment: I don't understand. You formulate one task and mark the solution to absolutely another task...

Comment: @Akina or you just misunderstood what was wanted.

Comment: Maybe... especially this sentence: *check for those where **col1** = col2 but they don't point to the same col1 value.*

Comment: @Akina yeah, I've learned to decipher the *real* meaning behind all kinds of confusing statements quite well. Sometimes you have to even dig the real question out of someone who doesn't know what he's asking (not here, but on SO side there's a lot of asking the wrong question).

Comment: I am sorry if my question was confusing. :(

Comment: No worries, you'll do better in your next question. This question would've been easier to understand had there been some example data and the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like

```
SELECT col2, col3 FROM table WHERE col2 = col3 GROUP BY col2, col3 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col1) > 1;
```

Would show you the col2/col3 combinations where col2 = col3 but col1 differs between those rows.

Answer (score 1):

> Akina: Сorrect me if I'm wrong. You want 1) Eject all records with col3 field values which not exists in any record in col2 field. 2) Select DISTINCT col1 for the remaining records.
>
> Andy Joe: @Akina col3 values which does exist in col2

Variant 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.col3 = t2.col2
```

Variant 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table1 t2 
              WHERE t1.col3 = t2.col2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! But it is taking unbearably long time to run self-join

Comment: @AndyJoe Try variant 2.